# how to create Class[] in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have to pass a Class[] from jni to java. 
I create the array in my native code as below,

```
array = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 10, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Class"), NULL);
```

I need to insert, Integer[].class and Integer.TYPE into this array and receive it in my java program.

```
public int Sample(Class[] cls){
   //some code
}
```

How can I insert the elements into the array in my jni layer using `SetObjectArrayElement()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I am using the more compact C++ JNI calls):

```
jclass classClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
jclass intClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jclass intArrayClass = env->FindClass("[java/lang/Integer";
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(intClass, "TYPE");
jclass intTypeClass = (jclass)env->GetStaticObjectField(intClass, fid);
jobjectArray array = env->NewObjectArray(2, classClass, 0);
env->SetObjectArrayElement(array, 0, intTypeClass);
env->SetObjectArrayElement(array, 1, intArrayClass);
```

Note that, depending on how this array is to be used, you may need to convert the array and its elements from local references to global references.